# Custom UITableView Cell auto layout issue with accessory when editing table

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, autolayout

I've created a custom cell with two UITextFields each in one side of the cell.

[image]

I'm using auto layout constrains with a fixed value for trailing and leading space between Content View and the left and right side UITextField.. Everything ok here.

The problem is when I set editing on the table.

[image]

As you can see the disclosure indicator get too close UITextField on the right not applying the auto layout constrains.

The constrains items are ok at runtime (I found in a similar question that on iOS7 sometimes the constrains items are switched from ContentView to the cell frame itself, but that's not the case)

Any idea? Thanks.

By request here's my cellForRow method (only the section with the problem) ..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    switch (indexPath.section)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            ...
        }
        case 1:
        {
            if ([self.tableView isEditing] && indexPath.row >= self.billMan.selectedBill.expenses.count)
            {
                cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"newCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
                ((UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1]).text = @"Add item";
            }
            else if (![tableView isEditing] && self.billMan.selectedBill.expenses.count == 0)
            {
                cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"newCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
                ((UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1]).text = @"No items";
            }
            else
            {
                cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"expenseCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
                UITextField *nameTextField = (UITextField*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
                UITextField *amountTextField = (UITextField*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
                BillExpense *expense = (BillExpense*)[self.billMan.selectedBill.expenses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                nameTextField.text = expense.name;
                amountTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$ %0.2f", expense.amount];
            }

            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            ...
        }
        default:
            break;
    }


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You should hide the UITableViewAccessory while editing.

Comment: I want the accessory to be available while editing..

Comment: What purpose does the accessory serve while editing?

Comment: It push another tableview controller with details about the amount and it automatically set editing on the pushed view controller if this one is editing. Also when editing it allows to modify the textfields. The point is I guess that it must be possible to keep te disclosure indicator even while editing because in interface builder there's an option for setting the accessory for editing mode (and another for non-editing mode accessory).

Comment: Could you post the cellForRowAtIndexPath: code?